# Is it true $f(x,y)$ and $af(x,y)$ has the maximum curvature at same point?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let assume function $f(x,y)$ has the max principle curvature at point $(x_0,y_0)$. And is it true $a\cdot f(x,y)$ ,($a\in\mathbb{R}$) has the max principle curvature at the same point? I think test some case using mathematica, and I think this is true, but I don’t know to how to prove it. Is my assumption true? And then how to prove it?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis do you mean some $p$ is constant at every point? If let $f (x, y) =xy$, then the principal curvature is $\sqrt{\frac{\left(x^2+1\right) \left(y^2+1\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)^3}}-\frac{x y}{\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$,and principal curvature of $f (x, y) =5xy$ is $5 \left(\sqrt{\frac{\left(25 x^2+1\right) \left(25 y^2+1\right)}{\left(25 x^2+25 y^2+1\right)^3}}-\frac{25 x y}{\left(25 x^2+25 y^2+1\right)^{3/2}}\right)$. their ratio is not constant.

Comment: My mistake, it's not as simple as I thought in the moment. I'm now thinking it's probably not true - you can certainly find examples of surfaces where the points of maximum curvature move when you stretch in one axis (e.g. a spheroid $x^2+y^2+2z^2 = 1$ can be stretched the to the spheroid $x^2 + y^2 + z^2/2 =1$). Can't think of a graphical counterexample off the top of my head but I suspect there's one out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity let's consider the case where $\partial f / \partial y = 0$, so that we just have the graph $(x,y,f(x))$. In this case one of the principal curvatures is zero, while the other is $$\kappa(x) = \frac{f''(x)}{(1+f'(x)^2)^{3/2}}.$$

If we try $f(x) = a x^3$, we get $$\kappa(x) = \frac{6ax}{(1+9a^2 x^4)^{3/2}}.$$

If you plot this curvature for $a=1$ and $a=5$ it's pretty clear the extrema occur at different points: [image: graph]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and then if $f (x, y) $ has the maximum principal curvature at $ (0,0) $, is it true both functions has the max principal value at the $ (0,0) $? I test the case of several cases, it seems like true.

Comment: @kyj519: no, you could just translate this example to put the maximum at the origin.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I realize I just think like a fool.